# changing html values using javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an unusual question, I think.
I have a table with different values.
e.g

```
 |   1  |   2.50  |   (1)4.75  |      2     |
 | 0.75 |     4   |    7.50    |      5     |
 | (1)3 | (6.50)4 |   (2)4.50  | (0.75)2.50 |
```

I would like to change the displayed values in this way:

`2.50 = +2`

`4.75 = -5`

and so on...
(note that I can only have two values after dot (.50 or .75) )

The result should look something like this:

```
 |   1  |    +2  |   (1)-5  |     2     |
 |  -1  |    4   |    +7    |     5     |
 | (1)3 |  (+6)4 |   (2)+4  |  (-1)+2   |
```

I would like to use javascript or Jquery for this. Simpler solution is better.

**Edit:**

I know it can be hard to undertand but it's not that hard as it is.

So, first of all i populate table like:

```
foreach ($list as $lk -> $lv)
{
  if($lv['addi_id'] != '')
  {
    ?>
       <td class='tdClass'>( <?php echo $lv['id']?> ) <?php echo $lv['addi_id'] ?> </td>
    <?php
  }
  else
  {
     ?>
       <td class='tdClass'><?php echo $lv['id'] ?></td>
     <?php
}
```

so this is why i'm getting table:

```
|   1  |   2.50  |   (1)4.75  |      2     |
| 0.75 |     4   |    7.50    |      5     |
| (1)3 | (6.50)4 |   (2)4.50  | (0.75)2.50 |
```

Now, i need to change only decimal numbers:

`1.50 = +1`
`1.75 = -2`
`2 = 2`
`2.50 = +2`
`2.75 = -3`
`3 = 3`

`(1.50)2 = (+1)2` 
`(1.75)2 = (-2)2` 
`(4)5.50 = (4)+5` 
`(5)5.75 = (5)-6`

And so on. This is why the output looks like this:

```
|   1  |    +2  |   (1)-5  |     2     |
|  -1  |    4   |    +7    |     5     |
| (1)3 |  (+6)4 |   (2)+4  |  (-1)+2   |
```

Comment: anyone able to understand the requirement?

Comment: Simpler or harder later....you should try first.

Comment: I tried with math.floor but it's not working :(

Comment: That is nowhere in the question.

Comment: Provide a properly explained relationship between input and output and show us what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective is for you to attempt to code your own solution and others help you fix **your code**

Comment: I understand what you want, but this seems an algorithm matter, nor a code matter. Think by yourself a way to write a javascript  function that receives an input value and returns it as you want. First, think what the funtion must do, step by step, and then write the code. It's not difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreted your question as this: a decimal number should be rounded (0.5 down) and a leading sign needs to be added: `-` if rounded up, `+` if rounded down

```js
function formatDecimals(decimalNumber) {
  var decimalNumber = parseFloat(decimalNumber)
  var integerPart = Math.floor(decimalNumber);
  var decimal = decimalNumber - integerPart
  var increment = decimal > 0.5 ? 1 : 0
  var sign = decimal > 0.5 ? '-' : '+'
  return sign + (integerPart + increment)
}

function format(numberString) {
  return numberString.replace(/\d+\.\d+/g, formatDecimals)
}

function test(expected, actual) {
  console.log(`[${expected===actual}] ${expected}, ${actual}`)
}

test('-1', format('0.75'))
test('-1(1)', format('0.75(1)'))
test('+1', format('1.50'))
test('(-1)+2', format('(0.75)2.50'))
```

Since 0.5 needts to be rounded down, I had to avoid `Math.round` and do some funny stuff with `floor`

Comment: that's cool stuff :) but there is one problem.  `(1)4.75` = `(+1.75` and yes, without `)` at the end

Comment: yeah, forgot to escape the dot in the regex

Comment: Oh gosh... you actually did it ! Thanks you so much :)